# Add image to the left of text

Tags: html, css, inline, paragraph

I am needing to create content for a page with a small icon image to the left of one sentence of content.

I would think this would be fairly simple to figure out, but I can't get the text to align with the bottom part of the image.
See attached image for example of what I am trying to figure out.
[image]
This is the code I have been using:

```html
<p>
<img src="http://www.example.com/smiley.jpg" alt="Smiley face image" 
style="float:left; width:42px; height:42px;"><span style="vertical-align:bottom">This 
is one line of text with image on the left side</span>
</p>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with CSS flexbox, adding `display: flex` to the paragraph, and align the text element `align-self: flex-end;`. Read more about [Flexbox at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox).

Using `float` is nowadays considered a bad practice since there are better alternatives.

```css
.text {
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.image {
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
}

.paragraph {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<p class="paragraph">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/OxHKeTw.gif" alt="Smiley face image" class="image"><span class="text">This is one line of text with image on the left side</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use `float:left`? Why not just insert the image as an `inline-block` at the beginning of the line? You can add padding to keep it separated from the start of the text if you like.

```html
<p><img src="http://placekitten.com/42/42" alt="" 
style="display:inline-block; padding-right:10px; width:42px; height:42px;">This 
is one line of text with image on the left side</p>
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for the solutions!! This example worded for the page. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to use position

```
<p style="position: relative; overflow: auto">
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e0/SNice.svg/1200px-SNice.svg.png"
     alt="Smiley face image"
     style="float:left; width:42px; height:42px;">
<span style="position:absolute; bottom: 0">This is one line of text with image on the left side</span>
```